# How to efficiently add a date column from a lookup table, without plyr?

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

I have two data tables. One, let's call it `procedures`, contains the procedures done to a patient, and has a patient pseudonym in each row.

```
Pseudonym    procedure 
AAA          CT scan 
AAA          glucose infusion 
AAB          abdominal surgery
```

The second one, a lookup table called `allo.dt`, assigns each patient pseudonym a special date, such as

```
pseudonym   erstes.tx.datum 
AAA         2014-01-10
AAB         2018-08-17
```

What I want is to add a column to the first data table, where in each row, I have the value of "erstes.tx.datum" from the second one.

```
Pseudonym    procedure          tx.datum 
AAA          CT scan            2014-01-10
AAA          glucose infusion   2014-01-10
AAB          abdominal surgery  2018-08-17
```

I am very new to data tables and failed to do it with a join.

```
setkey(procedures, Pseudonym)
setkey(allo.dt, pseudonym)
b <- merge(a, allo.dt, all.x=TRUE)
> A non-empty vector of column names for `by` is required.
```

This was surprising, when searching for doing a left join on data.table I didn't find any examples that needed a "by". I suspect that maybe the problem is that the pseudonym is obviously not the key in the procedures table, since it is not unique, but this is not something I can change.

Instead, I tried to use `sapply`. There I had two problems. First, the performance was terrible. Second, a naive access to the date gave me back a table cell instead of the value inside it, which led to a coercion of my date to an integer.

```
class(allo.dt[allo.dt$pseudonym=="AAA","erstes.tx.datum"])
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

I found an ugly workaround by turning that table cell into a single-element matrix, but it is practically illegible, and the performance is even worse. The whole solution I have is

> procedures$erstes.tx.datum -> unlist(sapply(ops.procedures$Pseudonym, function(x) {as.matrix(allo.dt[allo.dt$pseudonym==x,"erstes.tx.datum"])[1,1]}))

I am pretty sure there must be a much easier solution here, because that's what data.table is for, but I'm stuck. What would be a good way to do this?

I am aware that this has been asked in [Merging a data frame and a lookup table in r, retaining all records from data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069972/merging-a-data-frame-and-a-lookup-table-in-r-retaining-all-records-from-data-fr), but there the OP uses data frames and the answers suggest using `plyr`. I am looking specifically for a solution based on `data.table` or base r, without using `plyr`.

Comment: Since the column names are different (in capitalization), you need to tell `merge` how to line them up. Add `by.x = "Psuedonym", by.y = "psuedonym"`. Or, more simply, modify the tables so the column to match on has the same name.

Comment: @Gregor--reinstateMonica-- so, you mean that the "setkey" is not doing the "tell merge how to line them up" part? Because that's how I understood the tutorial at https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html and other examples I found.

Comment: You could do `dt2[dt1, tx.datum := tx.datum, on = .(Pseudonym = pseudonym)]` (data.table syntax)

Comment: I mean that the error message you get, *"A non-empty vector of column names for `by` is required."* is pretty clearly saying you need to specify columns in the `by` argument, so I would try doing that. And in the example you link, the columns already have the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the columns you want to merge by do not have the same name in both data frames, you need to specify how they should line up. In `merge`, this is done with the `by` argument. You can also use data table's `[` syntax for merging, in which uses an `on` argument.

Whether or not you set key, either of these will work:

```
merge(proc, allo, by.x = "Pseudonym", by.y = "pseudonym")
proc[allo, on = .(Pseudonym = pseudonym)]
```

So, what does `setkey` do? Most importantly, it will speed up any merges involving key columns. As far as the merge defaults, we can look at `?data.table::merge`, which begins:

> ...by default, it attempts to merge
>
> - at first based on the shared key columns, and if there are none,
> - then based on key columns of the first argument `x`, and if there are none,
> - then based on the common columns between the two data.tables.
>
> Set the `by`, or `by.x` and `by.y` arguments explicitly to override this default.

This is different than `base::merge`, in that `base::merge` will always try to merge on *all* shared columns. `data.table::merge` will prioritize shared columns *that are keyed* to merge on. None of these will attempt to merge columns with different names.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I was mislead by a comment in a tutorial which I interpreted to say that "setkey" does the job. Now it's clear.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with base R, where `match()` is used

```
df1$"tx.datum" <- df2$erstes.tx.datum[match(df1$Pseudonym,df2$pseudonym)]
```

such that

```
> df1
  Pseudonym         procedure   tx.datum
1       AAA           CT scan 2014-01-10
2       AAA  glucose infusion 2014-01-10
3       AAB abdominal surgery 2018-08-17
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is tidyverse based solution. It easily allows joining with mismatching column names.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

procedures%>%
left_join(allo.dt,by=c("Pseudonym"="pseudonym"))
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!